Llenar un DataGridView en C# con datos especificos de un Excel
Que tal me podrian apoyar con siguiente problematica en la que me encuentro. En mi proyecto c# obtengo cierto filtro de datos de un archivo en excel con ExcelDataReader, y estos necesito mostrarlo en un DataGridView sin embargo a la hora de hacerlo solo puedo mostrar el ultimo registro en una fila y necesito que se muestren todas las filas. Les dejo mi fragmento de mi codigo en donde me encuentro detenido es el segundo ciclo FOR.
for (i = 0; i < contadorFilas; i++)
{
  var columna = excel.Columns[0];
  int leerColumna = excel.Columns.IndexOf(columna);
  var resultado = excel.Rows[i][leerColumna].ToString();
   
  //Aqui aplico una comparativa que requiero//

  for (j = 0; j < contadorColumnas; j++) 
  {
    var recorrerColumna = excel.Columns[j];
    int leerColumnas = excel.Columns.IndexOf(recorrerColumna);
    valor = excel.Rows[i][leerColumnas].ToString();

    for (int x = 0; x <= dataGridViewDatos.RowCount - 1; x++) 
    {
     dataGridViewDatos.Rows[x].Cells[j].Value = valor;

  }
}




El código está incompleto, por ejemplo valor = excel.Rows[i][leerColumnas].ToString(); de donde sale i ???

El codigo esta completamente al reves.. primero recorres columnas y luego filas??? raro....

Si, esta incompleto (me falto colocar un ciclo FOR mas, que incluye  el codigo que publique y ahi obtengo i).

@gbianchi exactamente asi lo hago, lo que pasa necesito identificar cierta columna donde trae una clave que posteriomente obtengo datos de esa clave recorriendo esa fila. Sin embargo si los lee pero no logro mostar N claves con su información correspondiente en un datagridview solo me muestra el ultimo fila que encuentra.

@Yussef ya actualize mi código.

Tienes una tabla y la recorres desde el extremo superior izquierdo hacia la derecha y luego hacia abajo.
Tus primeros 2 for te posicionan en una casilla del excel, donde obtienes el valor de la primera columna (¿Entonces para que recorrer todas las columnas si siempre quieres la primera?, no entiendo eso). Pero el punto es que obtienes un valor de una celda
Cada vez que haces eso, recorres el DataGridView y modificas TODAS sus celdas con ese valor, y con todas me refiero a absolutamente todas (filas y columnas) luego para la siguiente fila del excel vuelves a hacer lo mismo y es por eso que siempre te muestra el último valor
Luego tienes el tema que solo modificas el DataGridView, es decir ese código solo funciona si previamente el DataGridView tiene una cantidad de filas y columnas exactamente igual al excel. Voy a suponer que es así y que eso está correcto, entonces simplemente haces:
for (int i = 0; i < excel.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < excel.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = excel.Rows[i][j].ToString();
    }
}

Ahora si tu solo quieres copiar UNA columna del excel, digamos que la primera como muestra en tu código (es decir la cero), sería:
for (int i = 0; i < excel.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = excel.Rows[i][0].ToString();
}

Porque si la columna es fija, no es necesario agregar un for adicional
